# Edit or convert Foreflight checklist file (.fmd)

Tags: windows, editor, file-converter

I am looking for software to edit or convert `.fmd` files created by ForeFlight.

ForeFlight has a checklist feature. I want to edit these either online or in a piece of software (instead of the app itself, because it is a pain). I am able to share the checklist to for example my email, where I found out the app creates a `.fmd` file.

Unfortunately I can't seem to open this file in any apps or converters. Maybe it is decrypted, I don't know.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I could possibly open this file?

If I open the `.fmd` file in notepad, I get something like this:

```
œñü‹z%{Øãï0rû$!¸ÅÞË­æ³±¿UqÏ}9ŸØÑúyëkW×@2ŒÏhQ¾à‚CNOE»@d2\9ìLývÙôŸÃ$Õ1-q%m¶+eæÊË"Ì 7¨SS†7š¿c^ˆnÒ>l Í<Dõ,Øuš‘9[    BçÑà:ž¿-ºS<¬h®Ðe¤¢¾”ï—ô(4É"Ô–[Ä@õwé{v¹5ð9 [Âû¬÷ºe¤Ð{DµìÀPI‘pÆjT|Üý’ßm
```

P.S. I contacted ForeFlight support, and they say there is no such software, nor intention to make this software. So I'm relying on you.

Comment: have you made any progress on this? I am in the same boat as you.